# Google Maps information box

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

How can I display an information box with a directions button like this?

[image]

I am using the Google Maps API. I already searched on google but I found nothing about how to include this box.

This is my current code:

```js
try {

  var point = {
    lat: 37.3316756,
    lng: 122.030189,

  };
  var markerSize = {
    x: -230,
    y: 70
  };


  google.maps.Marker.prototype.setLabel = function(label) {
    this.label = new MarkerLabel({
      map: this.map,
      marker: this,
      text: label
    });
    this.label.bindTo('position', this, 'position');
  };

  var MarkerLabel = function(options) {
    this.setValues(options);
    this.span = document.createElement('span');
    this.span.className = 'map-marker-label';
  };

  MarkerLabel.prototype = $.extend(new google.maps.OverlayView(), {
    onAdd: function() {
      this.getPanes().overlayImage.appendChild(this.span);
      var self = this;
      this.listeners = [
        google.maps.event.addListener(this, 'position_changed', function() {
          self.draw();
        })
      ];
    },
    draw: function() {
      var text = String(this.get('text'));
      var position = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.get('position'));
      this.span.innerHTML = text;
      this.span.style.left = (position.x - (markerSize.x / 2)) - (text.length * 3) + 10 + 'px';
      this.span.style.top = (position.y - markerSize.y + 40) + 'px';
    }
  });

  function initialize() {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat, point.lng);
    var gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 16,
      center: myLatLng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

    });
    var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: gmap,
      position: myLatLng,
      label: 'Apple Inc.',
    });
  }

  initialize();
} catch (e) {
  alert(e);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: About the direction, you can use the [direction service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) of google. About the saving, where do you want to save it?

Comment: Thank you. It should look like the box on the picture. When I use the Google Maps iframe code there is already this box.

Comment: Yes, but you want to use google maps **api** but not the embed option, right?

Comment: Right. But I already found a [solution](http://jsbin.com/pahoseguvi/edit?html,css,js,output) But thanks for your fast answers!

Comment: Nice :) It's not a generic solution, but nice. You can post the code as an answer so it can be helpful to other people..

Comment: Thank you! Done ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. It's not a generic solution but it's the easiest way:

HTML:

```
<div id="map"></div>

<!-- Scripts: Google maps and jquery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Card options
  var myOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.942693, 6.868371),
    zoom: 17,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false
  };

  // Render card
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

  // Append card when map renders
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function(e) {

    // Prevents card from being added more than once (i.e. when page is resized and google maps re-renders)
    if ( $( ".place-card" ).length === 0 ) {
    $(".gm-style").append('<div style="position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px;"> <div style="margin: 10px; padding: 1px; -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 0px 1px 4px -1px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 0px 1px 4px -1px; border-radius: 2px; background-color: white;"> <div> <div class="place-card place-card-large"> <div class="place-desc-large"> <div class="place-name"> Tenuta Cigliano </div><div class="address"> Contrada Pisciarelli, 80078 Napoli, Italy </div></div><div class="navigate"> <div class="navigate"> <a class="navigate-link" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=40.837067,14.136834&amp;z=16&amp;t=m&amp;hl=en-US&amp;gl=PT&amp;mapclient=embed&amp;daddr=Tenuta%20Cigliano%20Contrada%20Pisciarelli%2080078%20Napoli%20Italy@40.837067,14.142821" target="_blank"> <div class="icon navigate-icon"></div><div class="navigate-text"> Directions </div></a> </div></div><div class="review-box"> <div class="" style="display:none"></div><div class="" style="display:none"></div><div class="" style="display:none"></div><div class="" style="display:none"></div><div class="" style="display:none"></div><div class="" style="display:none"></div><a href="https://plus.google.com/101643431012640484007/about?hl=en&amp;authuser=0&amp;gl=pt&amp;socpid=247&amp;socfid=maps_embed:placecard" target="_blank">1 review</a> </div><div class="saved-from-source-link" style="display:none"> </div><div class="maps-links-box-exp"> <div class="time-to-location-info-exp" style="display:none"> <span class="drive-icon-exp experiment-icon"></span><a class="time-to-location-text-exp" style="display:none" target="_blank"></a><a class="time-to-location-text-exp" style="display:none" target="_blank"></a> </div><div class="google-maps-link"> <a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=40.837067,14.136834&amp;z=16&amp;t=m&amp;hl=en-US&amp;gl=PT&amp;mapclient=embed&amp;cid=2152474408176797502" target="_blank">View larger map</a> </div></div><div class="time-to-location-privacy-exp" style="display:none"> <div class="only-visible-to-you-exp"> Visible only to you. </div><a class="learn-more-exp" target="_blank">Learn more</a> </div></div></div></div></div>');
    }
  });

});
```

CSS:

```
/* Set a height for map */
#map {
  height: 500px;
}

/* Google maps card styles - COPIED */
.gm-style .place-card div,
.gm-style .place-card a,
.gm-style .default-card div,
.gm-style .default-card a {
  color: #5B5B5B;
  font-family: Roboto, Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  -moz-user-select: text;
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  -ms-user-select: text;
  user-select: text
}

.gm-style .place-card,
.gm-style .default-card,
.gm-style .directions-card {
  cursor: default
}

.gm-style .place-card-large {
  padding: 9px 4px 9px 11px
}

.gm-style .place-card-medium {
  width: auto;
  padding: 9px 11px 9px 11px
}

.gm-style .default-card {
  padding: 5px 14px 5px 14px
}

.gm-style .place-card a:link,
.gm-style .default-card a:link,
.gm-style .directions-card a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3a84df
}

.gm-style .place-card a:visited,
.gm-style .default-card a:visited,
.gm-style .directions-card a:visited {
  color: #3a84df
}

.gm-style .place-card a:hover,
.gm-style .default-card a:hover,
.gm-style .directions-card a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline
}

.gm-style .place-desc-large {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block
}

.gm-style .place-desc-medium {
  display: inline-block
}

.gm-style .place-card .place-name {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: black
}

html[dir="rtl"] .gm-style .place-name {
  padding-right: 5px
}

.gm-style .place-card .address {
  margin-top: 6px
}

.gm-style .tooltip-anchor {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  z-index: 1
}

.gm-style .star-entity .tooltip-anchor,
.gm-style .star-entity-medium .tooltip-anchor,
.gm-style .navigate-entity-medium .tooltip-anchor,
.gm-style .navigate .tooltip-anchor {
  width: 50%;
  display: none
}

.gm-style .star-entity:hover .tooltip-anchor,
.gm-style .star-entity-medium:hover .tooltip-anchor,
.gm-style .navigate-entity-medium:hover .tooltip-anchor,
.gm-style .navigate:hover .tooltip-anchor {
  display: inline
}

.gm-style .tooltip-anchor>.tooltip-tip-inner,
.gm-style .tooltip-anchor>.tooltip-tip-outer {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: -8px
}

.gm-style .tooltip-anchor>.tooltip-tip-outer {
  border-bottom: 8px solid #CBCBCB
}

.gm-style .tooltip-anchor>.tooltip-tip-inner {
  border-bottom: 8px solid white;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 1px
}

.gm-style .tooltip-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: -70px;
  line-height: 137%;
  padding: 10px 12px 10px 13px;
  width: 210px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #CBCBCB;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: white
}

html[dir="rtl"] .gm-style .tooltip-content {
  left: -10px
}

.gm-style .star-entity-medium .tooltip-content {
  width: 110px
}

.gm-style .navigate {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 43px;
  padding: 0 7px
}

.gm-style .navigate-entity-medium {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  margin-top: 1px
}

.gm-style .navigate-link {
  display: block
}

.gm-style .place-card .navigate-text,
.gm-style .place-card .star-entity-text {
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #3a84df;
  font-size: 12px;
  max-width: 55px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis
}

.gm-style .place-card .hidden {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden
}

.gm-style .navigate-icon {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.gm-style .navigate-icon {
  border: 0
}

.gm-style .navigate-separator {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1px;
  height: 43px;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fbfbfb, #e2e2e2, #fbfbfb);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fbfbfb, #e2e2e2, #fbfbfb);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fbfbfb, #e2e2e2, #fbfbfb);
  background: -linear-gradient(top, #fbfbfb, #e2e2e2, #fbfbfb)
}

.gm-style .star-entity {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 43px;
  padding: 0 7px
}

.gm-style .star-entity .star-button {
  cursor: pointer
}

.gm-style .navigate-entity .navigate-button {
  cursor: pointer
}

.gm-style .star-entity-medium {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  margin-top: 1px
}

.gm-style .star-entity:hover .star-entity-text {
  text-decoration: underline
}

.gm-style .star-entity-icon-large {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.gm-style .star-entity-icon-medium {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  top: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.gm-style .navigate-entity-icon-medium {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  top: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.gm-style .can-star-large {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.gm-style .logged-out-star,
.logged-out-star:hover {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.gm-style .is-starred-large {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.gm-style .can-star-medium {
  position: relative;
  height: 17px;
  top: -2px;
  cursor: pointer
}

.gm-style .is-starred-medium {
  position: relative;
  height: 17px;
  top: -2px;
  cursor: pointer
}

.gm-style .navigate-icon-medium {
  position: relative;
  height: 17px;
  top: -2px;
  cursor: pointer
}

.gm-style .review-box {
  padding-top: 5px
}

.gm-style .place-card .review-box-link {
  padding-left: 8px
}

.gm-style .place-card .review-number {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #e7711b;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px
}

.gm-style .rating-star {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  overflow: hidden
}

.gm-style .directions-card {
  color: #5B5B5B;
  font-family: Roboto, Arial;
  background-color: white;
  -moz-user-select: text;
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  -ms-user-select: text;
  user-select: text
}

.gm-style .directions-card-medium-large {
  height: 71px;
  padding: 10px 11px
}

.gm-style .directions-info {
  padding-left: 25px
}

.gm-style .directions-waypoint {
  height: 20px
}

.gm-style .directions-address {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 13px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  color: black
}

.gm-style .directions-icon {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-top: 2px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 20px
}

.gm-style .directions-icon div {
  width: 15px;
  height: 45px;
  overflow: hidden
}

.gm-style .directions-separator {
  position: relative;
  height: 1px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  background-color: #ccc
}

.gm-style .maps-links-box-exp {
  padding-top: 5px
}

.gm-style .time-to-location-info-exp {
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block
}

.gm-style .google-maps-link-exp {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle
}

.gm-style .time-to-location-text-exp {
  vertical-align: middle
}

.gm-style .place-card-large .only-visible-to-you-exp {
  padding-top: 5px;
  color: #ccc;
  display: inline-block
}

.gm-style .place-card-large .time-to-location-privacy-exp .learn-more-exp {
  color: #ccc;
  text-decoration: underline
}

.gm-style .navigate-icon {
  background-position: 0px 0px
}

.gm-style .navigate:hover .navigate-icon {
  background-position: 48px 0px
}

.gm-style .navigate-icon-medium {
  background-position: 0px 94px
}

.gm-style .navigate-icon-medium:hover {
  background-position: -16px 94px
}

.gm-style .can-star-large {
  background-position: 70px 187px
}

.gm-style .star-button:hover .can-star-large {
  background-position: 48px 187px
}

.gm-style .logged-out-star {
  background-position: 96px 187px
}

.gm-style .star-button:hover .logged-out-star {
  background-position: 96px 187px
}

.gm-style .is-starred-large {
  background-position: 0px 166px
}

.gm-style .rating-full-star {
  background-position: 48px 165px
}

.gm-style .rating-half-star {
  background-position: 35px 165px
}

html[dir="rtl"] .gm-style .rating-half-star {
  background-position: 10px 165px
}

.gm-style .rating-empty-star {
  background-position: 23px 165px
}

.gm-style .directions-icon {
  background-position: 0px 144px
}

.gm-style .hovercard-personal-icon-home {
  background-position: 96px 102px
}

.gm-style .hovercard-personal-icon-work {
  background-position: 96px 79px
}

.gm-style .can-star-medium {
  background-position: 0px 36px
}

.gm-style .can-star-medium:hover {
  background-position: -17px 36px
}

.gm-style .logged-out-star-medium {
  background-position: 36px 36px
}

.gm-style .star-button:hover .logged-out-star-medium {
  background-position: 36px 36px
}

.gm-style .is-starred-medium {
  background-position: 0px 19px
}

.gm-style .info {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-position: 19px 36px
}

.saved-from-source-link {
  margin-top: 5px;
  max-width: 331px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap
}

.gm-style .drive-icon-exp {
  background-position: -90px -62px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle
}

.gm-style .star-entity-icon-large-exp {
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.gm-style .can-star-large-exp {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.gm-style .logged-out-star-exp,
.logged-out-star-exp:hover {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.gm-style .is-starred-large-exp {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.gm-style .can-star-large-exp {
  background-position: -46px -46px
}

.gm-style .star-button-exp:hover .can-star-large-exp {
  background-position: -2px -46px
}

.gm-style .logged-out-star-exp {
  background-position: -46px -91px
}

.gm-style .star-button-exp:hover .logged-out-star-exp {
  background-position: -2px -46px
}

.gm-style .is-starred-large-exp {
  background-position: -2px -91px
}

.gm-style .star-button-exp {
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px
}

.gm-style .star-entity-exp .star-button-exp {
  cursor: pointer
}

.gm-style .navigate-icon-exp {
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.gm-style .navigate-icon-exp {
  border: 0
}

.gm-style .navigate-icon-exp {
  background-position: -46px -1px
}

.gm-style .navigate:hover .navigate-icon-exp {
  background-position: -2px -1px
}

.gm-style .navigate-exp {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 43px;
  padding: 0 7px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -18px
}

.gm-style .icon {
  background-image: url(https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/embed/images/entity11.png);
  background-size: 70px 210px;
}
```